# Previous java files are being replaced by the New java file in eclipse search

Tags: eclipse

I am using eclipse *Kepler* and *Mars*. I am facing a problem in eclipse like, if I search a particular file (java, jsp, or xml etc.) by using `ctrl + H` or File Search, a list of files related to the search is fetched in the **Search tab** of eclipse. When I clicked one of files to open it and then clicked another file, instead of opening 2 separate files, the previous file is getting replaced by the new one.

Then I have to copy the name of the previous file and open it again by using Open Resource or `ctrl + shift + R`. This problem is appearing all the time in the two eclipse IDE.

I don't know if anyone ever faced this problem, or this is being the normal nature of eclipse IDE. Please suggest an idea to overcome this issue. Is the version of the eclipse responsible for this problem?

My system's jdk version is 1.8. I also tried with jdk-1.6 environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Preferences and go to 'General > Search'.

Deselect the 'Reuse editors to show matches' option.